# How can I enhance ModelBinder in ASP.NET Core (update property values for a model class)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to enhance final result that `ModelBinder` returns.
For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Order {get;set;}

    [MyUpperCaseAttribute]
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

In API method I expect that all string properties in `MyModel` which has `MyUpperCaseAttribute` is in upper case.

For example:

```
[HttpPost("AddRecord")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> AddRecord(MyModel model)
{
    model.Title should be upper case, even if send from client in lower case.
}
```

My idea was to override default `ModelBinder` and enumerate through all properties and check if property is string and has `MyUpperCaseAttribute` and correct property value to upper case. I check documentation, but doesn't examples doesn't fill right, since they completely redesign what is returned. I would like to just modify result properties.

What would be the best option to achieve desired behaviour?

**Important:** (edited):
It would be nice if directive attributes could be stacked:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Order {get;set;}
    [MyUpperCaseAttribute]
    [RemoveSpacesAttribute]
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

**Edited:**
It looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319552/underscore-string-model-binder), but if not other, this is ASP.NET Core, and on link is just ASP.NET. Method, properties, interfaces... are not the same.

I should say, that it would be nice if JSON case rule would work:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Order {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

should work if `{order: 1, title: "test"}` (notice lowercase) is send from JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore string model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319552/underscore-string-model-binder)

Comment: @IanKemp It is not. It talks about ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET. There are different methods, names, interfaces, principles, implementations ...

Comment: There are a plethora of resources on how to write model binders for ASP.NET Core, surely you should be able to combine one of those with the answer I linked to to achieve what you require?

Comment: Underscore string model binder question talks how to bind one property. I am searching how to process entire model (change properties values).

Comment: Is the incoming model JSON serialised?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Not sure what this means, but I think yes. I uses Angular 2+. Content type is `content-type: application/json`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. In that case, the deserialisation will be using JSON.NET. You might be able to find something within JSON.NET itself that you can configure to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the 'best' option, but I would just use `.ToUpper()` extension method instead of a custom attribute filter.

```
public class MyModel
{
    private string _title;
    public int Order {get;set;}

    public string Title { get => _title.ToUpper(); set => _title = value.ToUpper(); }
}
```

Comment: It is an idea, but attribute would be a lot better (it's shorter, more transparent, it should work out of the box).

Answer (score 1):

There's a big red herring here, and that's the fact that it appears that this is the sort of thing that could and should be accomplished via model binding. Unfortunately, that's not the case in ASP.Net Core Web API: because the incoming data is JSON, it is in fact handled by [input formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters), not model binders. Therefore, in order to achieve the desired effect, you need to create your own custom input formatter that replaces the standard [`JsonInputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.jsoninputformatter).

First the attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ToUppercaseAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then we decorate our model class with it:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Order { get; set; }

    [ToUppercase]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now create our custom input formatter that checks for that attribute and transforms the output if necessary. In this case, it simply wraps and delegates to `JsonInputFormatter` to do the heavy lifting as normal, then modifies the result if it finds our `ToUppercaseAttribute` attribute on any `string` property:

```
public class ToUppercaseJsonInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    private readonly JsonInputFormatter _jsonInputFormatter;

    public ToUppercaseJsonInputFormatter(JsonInputFormatter jsonInputFormatter)
    {
        _jsonInputFormatter = jsonInputFormatter;

        foreach (var supportedEncoding in _jsonInputFormatter.SupportedEncodings)
            SupportedEncodings.Add(supportedEncoding);

        foreach (var supportedMediaType in _jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes)
           SupportedMediaTypes.Add(supportedMediaType);
    }

    public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var result = _jsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(context, encoding);

        foreach (var property in context.ModelType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))
            && p.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ToUppercaseAttribute)))))
        {
            var value = (string)property.GetValue(result.Result.Model);
            property.SetValue(result.Result.Model, value.ToUpper());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Next we create an extension method that makes it simple to substitute the default `JsonInputFormatter` with our custom formatter:

```
public static class MvcOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void UseToUppercaseJsonInputFormatter(this MvcOptions opts)
    {
        if (opts.InputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f is JsonInputFormatter && !(f is JsonPatchInputFormatter)) is JsonInputFormatter jsonInputFormatter)
        {
            var jsonInputFormatterIndex = opts.InputFormatters.IndexOf(jsonInputFormatter);
            opts.InputFormatters[jsonInputFormatterIndex] = new ToUppercaseJsonInputFormatter(jsonInputFormatter);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, call that method to effect the replacement in `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc(options => options.UseToUppercaseJsonInputFormatter());
    }
}
```

Et voilà!

Comment: Changed `JsonInputFormatter` to `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter` to make this work in .net core 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing inside your `MyUpperCaseAttribute` as follows:

```
public class MyUpperCaseAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(value != null)
        {
            validationContext.ObjectType
            .GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName)
            .SetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, value.ToString().ToUpper(), null);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Property value will be converted to `UpperCase` during `Model Binding`. I have checked it in my side and it works perfectly.

Comment: I would like to avoid that. Right now I have almost 100 different API calls and I would like to avoid writing this code in every API method. Also what if I use same `Model` in 2 different API methods. I would need to write this code in both methods. With `ModelBinder` only on one.

Comment: But still I need to call helper method in every API method. I would like to avoid that. Developer should define model class, on some code should take care of everything. Just as `Required` attribute. You don't write code in every API method to check if all `Required` properties are set.

Comment: I am sure it can be done automatically. Required, MaxLength ... all model validation works out of the box, this should also. I think this makes sense. Developer needs to edit only model class. Nothing else.

Comment: This answer is halfway there, it just needs to packaged into a custom `ModelBinder`. I've linked to a similar question that does the whole thing, hopefully that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @TanvirArjel  
I am just checking JsonContractResolver and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6884) since updating model in Validation sims a little strange. Will be back when I research things.